# Blocked a frame with origin <example.com> from accessing a frame with origin "https://<example2>.co" Protocols, domains, and ports must match

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, iframe, same-origin-policy, ionic5

In my ionic application

Component.html

```
<ion-content>
  <iframe #iframe height="100%" width="100%" title="test"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
this.iframe.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', this.gameUrl);
```

is succeesfully working but my gameUrl site is a core HTML site so when I navigate to second page of my game site by

```
window.location.replace(`https://<gamesh5app>/start.html?id=${userId}&gamePlay=${gamePlay}`);
```

It just close the iframe and window.onmessage method of my ionic application get called

and I am getting error message

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://gamesh5app" from accessing a
> frame with origin "https://exmaple.co". Protocols, domains, and ports
> must match.

Error only getting into IOS as into android it is working fine.

Please help.